# The bar level is not decreasing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two kind of bar. One of them is cheesebar.

When the mouse enters the trigger, it's decreasing which means the cheese is being eaten.

Other bar is hungerlevel, decreasing depending on the counter.

Here is my cheesebar code

```
Image cheesbar;
float maxcheese = 100f;
public static float cheese eaten;
float cheeseamount=0.1f;

void start ()
{
    cheesbar = GetComponent<Image>();
    cheeseeaten=maxcheese;    
}

void update()
{
    cheesbar.fillAmount=cheeseeaten/maxcheese;    
}

public void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    cheeseeaten-= cheeseamount+cheeseamount*Time.deltaTime;
    hungerscript.gettinghungery += cheeseamount + cheeeseamount* Time.deltaTime;
}
```

The problem is when the mouse enters the trigger (cheesebar) hungerbar is not increasing. And this is hungerbar update void.

```
void Update ()
{
    currenttime -= 1 * Time.deltaTime;
    hungerbar.fillAmount = gettinghungery  / maxhunger;
}
```

I think the problem is update function is renewing hungerbar and it blocks that cheese.

Comment: This can be closed as "typo or no repro" - the answer is probably not going to be helpful to any other readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Change the "update()" method name to "Update()"

You are assuming that Unity will call your `update()` method, when it's looking to call a method called `Update()`.

Comment: Same goes for the `start()` too, it needs to be `Start()`

Comment: by the way I decided to eat the chees by pressing button with pointerdown function....when I press it the cheese is being eaten but hungerbar is not increasing again ....but with the old method I mean when I put the code into the Update function works normally but with button does not work. do you have any idea. ?

Comment: You would not call `Update()` directly. I would move your cheese eating code into its own method